# Find command regextype difference between 'posix-extended' and 'posix-egrep'

Tags: regex, shell, grep, sh

The title really says it all. Can anyone point me to where I could find descriptions of the different regex types available to the find command. I'm able to find a list of them but no explanations or comparisons. In particular, what could the difference be between 'posix-egrep' and 'posix-extended,' since egrep is a tool for regex matching according to the extended set?

Comment: GNU implements extensions to ERE. `\<` and `\>` for beginning-of-word and end-of-word, for example, aren't part of the baseline POSIX standard. Not saying that these are the differences, but *definitely* saying that there exist differences.

Comment: ...that said, this is more a [unix.se] question than a StackOverflow question. Note the phrase "unique to software development" in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic -- if a question is of interest to command-line users (as opposed to scripted use), it's outside our scope.

Comment: To see the differences in `posix-extended` and `posix-egrep` check here: https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/posix_002dextended-regular-expression-syntax.html#posix_002dextended-regular-expression-syntax, they are one page apart.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let me guide through you how you should use linux's documentation to self-answer questions like this by showing you how exactly I locate information.

1. I run `man find` to see some basic information of regular expression type by searching the keyword, `regular`, then I see this:

> -regextype type
>
> Changes the regular expression syntax understood by -regex and -iregex tests which occur later on the command line.  To see which regular expression types are  known,  use
>                 -regextype help.  The Texinfo documentation (see SEE ALSO) explains the meaning of and differences between the various types of regular expression.

Assuming this is what you are looking for, the doc says it's in `Texinfo`, so I do the next step;

2. run `info find`. Then search `regextype` to locate the correct section for it. Then I reached:

> '--regextype'
>
> This option changes the regular expression syntax and behaviour
>        used by the '--regex' option.  *note Regular Expressions:: for more
>        information on the regular expression dialects understood by GNU
>        findutils.

It asks to refer to a further documentation named **note Regular Expressions**, which you can go to there by hitting enter when cursor's on it.

3. Hooray!

> - Menu:
> - findutils-default regular expression syntax::
> - awk regular expression syntax::
> - egrep regular expression syntax::
> - emacs regular expression syntax::
> - gnu-awk regular expression syntax::
> - grep regular expression syntax::
> - posix-awk regular expression syntax::
> - posix-basic regular expression syntax::
> - posix-egrep regular expression syntax::
> - posix-extended regular expression syntax::

The last two items are exactly what you are asking. Read both of them, and then you can find out that the system already has the proper answers for you.

Comment: Oh my...
`--regextype type
Changes the regular expression syntax understood by -regex and -iregex tests which occur later on the command line.  Currently-implemented types are emacs (this is the default),  posix-awk, posix-basic, posix-egrep and posix-extended.`
The `info find` really works as you said. Thank you.

Comment: Nice write up ... really teaches a man how to fish

Answer (score 8):

According to the info docs, they are very similar, with the following differences:

### [posix-egrep](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/posix_002degrep-regular-expression-syntax.html#posix_002degrep-regular-expression-syntax)

The character '.' matches any single character.

The characters '*', '+' and '?' are special anywhere in a regular expression.

Intervals are specified by '{' and '}'.  Invalid intervals are treated as literals, for example 'a{1' is treated as 'a{1'

### [posix-extended](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/posix_002dextended-regular-expression-syntax.html#posix_002dextended-regular-expression-syntax)

The character '.' matches any single character except the null character.

'*', '+' and '?' are special at any point in a regular expression
except the following places, where they are not allowed:

1. At the beginning of a regular expression
2. After an open-group, signified by '('
3. After the alternation operator '|'

Intervals are specified by '{' and '}'.  Invalid intervals such as
'a{1z' are not accepted.